# Подключение к бд informix при помощи entity framework c#

Tags: c#, база-данных, entity-framework, entity, ibm

Прочитал данные кучу статей, сделал все как там. НО! у меня не отображается в Db explorer база данных информикс.

Поставил:

- IBM Data Studio client Install for Windows
- IBM Data Server Client
- IBM Data Server Runtime Client
- IBM Data Server Driver Package (DS Driver)
- IBM Data Server Driver for ODBC and CLI (CLI Driver)
- IBM Informix Client SDK
- IBM Database Add-Ins for Visual Studio
- Data Studio 4.1.2 Client

и ничего. Кто нибудь может быть работал этой базой? через ef?

Answer (score 0):

Нашел [статью](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/96960515-2ea1-4391-8170-b0515d08e4da/entry/Getting_Started_with_IBM_Entity_Framework_6_Database_First_using_MVC_5_on_Windows_10?lang=en). Попробовал - ничего не вышло.

Единственный способ, который у меня работает - это OleDbConnection. 
Для этого нужно всего 1 вещь:

> clientsdk.3.50.TC4DE.WIN. Версии 3.70 и 4.10 не такие стабильные, как
>   v3.50.

Пример подключения :

```
private static string connectionStringInformix =
           "Provider=IBM INFORMIX OLE DB Provider;Data     Source=TABLENAME@SERVERNAME;Persist Security Info=True;Password=password;User  ID=user"; 

        OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionStringInformix);
                 connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("select count(id) from  table", connection);
            int maxNumber = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar()) + 1;
```